# VTK Cmake VTK_BUILD_TESTING

Tags: macos, cmake, vtk, cmake-gui

My system is Mac and I'm trying to set VTK_BUILD_TESTING (Cmake option) to 'ON'.
But the error is like the picture below. I've searched for the information. None of them are not working. What should I do to fix the error?

I downloaded VTK from (https://github.com/Kitware/VTK)

[image]

Comment: "But the error is like the picture below." - Please, add into the question post also a **text** with this error message. Among other reasons, having an error message in *textual* form is a requirement of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `BUILD_TESTING` to `WANT` instead of `ON`

The modularization of VTK have been rewritten recently with more flexibility.

- ON means that you want to enable it and all that it depends on, **no matter what**.
- WANT means that you want to activate it and all dependencies that **can** be activated.

See here for more info : 
https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/vtk-developers/2019-January/036648.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so is there no way to set the BUILD_TESTING to 'ON'?

Comment: You would need to enable all the missing modules manually. with WANT, you still get the tests enabled for all the modules that are automatically enabled, see it should be enough for you.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't seem all that hard to figure out (unless you have to squint at a screenshot to see the error.)

```
VTK::RenderingFreeType module requires the disabled module
  VTK::RenderingMatplotlib
```

Ergo, you need to find out why `VTK::RenderingMatplotlib` is disabled. You need to look at the full CMake output to determine what caused it to be disabled. Since you haven't included it, and you haven't said what you have tried thus far beyond googling the error string, nobody is able to tell you precisely what is wrong.

Look for `RenderingMatplotlib` in your CMake output and logs to determine what the issue is. If you have Matplot installed, it may be as easy as enabling the module.

Comment: "You need to look at **further** CMake output to determine that." - There is no more output from CMake, the last 3 lines shown are the last 3 lines in any CMake configuration log reporting the error. Or do you mean to look into **previous** lines?

Comment: I also wonder about it. There is no more line. Could explain how to check it more in detail?